# Count the number of unique occurrences in an array that contain a specific string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my javascript array:

```
arr = ['blue-dots', 'blue', 'red-dots', 'orange-dots', 'blue-dots'];
```

With Javascript, how can I count the total number of all unique values in the array that contain the string “dots”. So, for the above array the answer would be 3 (blue-dots, orange-dots, and red-dots).

Comment: use regular quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: This other question doesn't explain how to also only count elements that contain the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = 0,
    arr1 = [];    
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].indexOf('dots') !== -1) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) {
            count++;
            arr1.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
 }
```

you check if a certain element contains 'dots', and if it does, you check if it is already in arr1, if not increment count and add element to arr1.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to store element as key of an object, then get the count of the keys:

```js
var arr = ["blue-dots", "blue", "red-dots", "orange-dots", "blue-dots"];
console.log(Object.keys(arr.reduce(function(o, x) {
  if (x.indexOf('dots') != -1) {
    o[x] = true;
  }
  return o
}, {})).length)
```

Comment: elegant, but could be improved, altho like it +1

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array), I got the `getUnique` function.

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}
```

then you can add a function that counts ocurrences of a string inside an array of strings:

```
function getOcurrencesInStrings(targetString, arrayOfStrings){
  var ocurrencesCount = 0;
  for(var i = 0, arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
    if(arrayOfStrings[i].indexOf(targetString) > -1){
      ocurrencesCount++;
    }
  }
  return ocurrencesCount;
}
```

then you just:

```
getOcurrencesInStrings('dots', initialArray.getUnique())
```

This will return the number you want.

It's not the smallest piece of code, but It's highly reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this something like this:

```
// Create a custom function
function countDots(array) {
  var count = 0;

  // Get and store each value, so they are not repeated if present.
  var uniq_array = [];
  array.forEach(function(value) {
    if(uniq_array.indexOf(value) == -1) {
      uniq_array.push(value);

      // Add one to count if 'dots' word is present.
      if(value.indexOf('dots') != -1) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
  });

  return count;
}

// This will print '3' on console
console.log( countDots(['blue-dots', 'blue', 'red-dots', 'orange-dots', 'blue-dots']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var uniqueHolder = {};
var arr = ["blue-dots", "blue", "red-dots", "orange-dots", "blue-dots"];
arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.indexOf('dots') > -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(item) {
    uniqueHolder[item] ? void(0) : uniqueHolder[item] = true;
  });
console.log('Count: ' + Object.keys(uniqueHolder).length);
console.log('Values: ' + Object.keys(uniqueHolder));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [ "blue-dots", "blue", "red-dots", "orange-dots", "blue-dots" ];
var fArr = []; // Empty array, which could replace arr after the filtering is done.
arr.forEach( function( v ) {
  v.indexOf( "dots" ) > -1 && fArr.indexOf( v ) === -1 ? fArr.push( v ) : null;
  // Filter if "dots" is in the string, and not already in the other array.
});

// Code for displaying result on page, not necessary to filter arr

document.querySelector( ".before" ).innerHTML = arr.join( ", " );
document.querySelector( ".after" ).innerHTML = fArr.join( ", " );
```

```html
Before:
<pre class="before">
  </pre>
After:
<pre class="after">
  </pre>
```

To put this simply, it will loop through the array, and if dots is in the string, AND it doesn't already exist in `fArr`, it'll push it into `fArr`, otherwise it'll do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
arr = ["blue-dots", "blue", "red-dots", "orange-dots", "blue-dots"];

sample = [];    
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ((arr[i].indexOf('dots') !== -1) && (sample.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1)){
       sample.push(arr[i]);

    }
 }

alert(sample.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate the operations of string comparison and returning unique items, to make your code easier to test, read, and reuse.

```js
var unique = function(a){
    return a.length === 0 ? [] : [a[0]].concat(unique(a.filter(function(x){
        return x !== a[0];
    })));
};

var has = function(x){
    return function(y){
        return y.indexOf(x) !== -1;
    };
};

var arr = ["blue-dots", "blue", "red-dots", "orange-dots", "blue-dots"];
var uniquedots = unique(arr.filter(has('dots')));
console.log(uniquedots);
console.log(uniquedots.length);
```